# Django Rest Framework: Converting a model object number into its corresponding string

Tags: python, django, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I've an application which contains two different models, related by a Many-to-Many relationship as follows:

```
from django.db import models


class Genres(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)

class Movies(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genres, related_name = 'movies')
    imdb_score = models.FloatField()
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

serializers.py

```
from shoppy.models import Movies, Genres
from rest_framework import serializers


class GenresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Genres
        fields = ('genre',)

class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #genre = serializers.CharField(max_length = 128, choices = Movies.GENRE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = ('popularity', 'director', 'imdb_score', 'genre',
                        'movie_name')
```

This is how my API endpoint form at `http://localhost:8000/movies/` looks like:

[image]

Now, instead of different `genres` appearing as instances of `Genres` object numbers, how can I make them appear as the actual string corresponding to each object number? For example, `Genres object-1` corresponds to `Comedy`, and that is what I want to be displayed in the API endpoint form to make the genre choices more human-readable.

What's the way to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `__str__` method in your `Genres` model.

```
class Genres(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'%self.genre
```

Comment: This works just fine. However, in the generated JSON format, the selected `genres` are still displayed with their corresponding numerical values. How do I make them appear as their string equivalents in the generated API formats?

Comment: By numerical values, you mean the `genre` ids? Can you post a sample json

Comment: Yes, the genres are being represented by their respective ids in the generated API format.

Comment: You might need to override the `to_represention`  method for `ManyToManyField` and then return `str(value)` instead of `value.pk` which it is returning now.`str(value)` will call the `__str__` method of `Genres` model.

Comment: In your serializer, you need to define the `depth` property of `class Meta`. Setting `depth = 1` should give you the representation you are looking for,